# coffee require() statements causing circular references?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I've got a weird problem with Coffeescript not properly caching/finishing loading require() statements that are being referenced in a circular fashion.

When I run this code with *node main.js*...

**main.js**

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'John'
}

var config = require('./config');
config.hello();
```

**config.js**

```
var main = require('./main');

module.exports = {
    hello: function() {
        console.log("Hello " + main.name);
    }
}
```

... I get the following output:

> Hello John

However, when I run the equivalent coffeescript code with *coffee main.coffee*...

**main.coffee**

```
module.exports =
    name: 'John'

config = require './config'
config.hello()
```

**config.coffee**

```
main = require './main'

module.exports =
    hello: ->
        console.log "hello #{main.name}"
```

... I get this:

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'hello'

When I compile the code to plain ol' Javascript and run via node, it's fine.

What's going on with *coffee*?

Comment: afaik coffee script has always to be compiled before executed.

Comment: it does, but the 'coffee' app that comes free with npm install -g coffee-script is what produced the behaviour above -- I'm trying to avoid the compilation cycle every time I want to test a development code change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My theory is this behavior is a combination of how the node.js `require` cache works, how node handles cyclical dependencies, and something about how the coffee transpiler works when loading `.coffee` files straight into node.

I made distinct coffeescript and javascript versions of the program with illustrative logging as follows. I used "maincs" and "mainjs" to make sure there was no mixing of the two languages.

**mainjs.js**

```
console.log("mainjs starting");
console.log("mainjs exporting name");
module.exports = {
  name: 'John'
};
console.log("mainjs requiring configjs");

var configjs = require('./configjs');

console.log("mainjs calling configjs.hello()");

configjs.hello();
```

**configjs.js**

```
console.log("configjs starting");
console.log("configjs requiring mainjs");
var mainjs = require("./mainjs");
console.log("configjs exporting hello");
module.exports = {
  hello: function() {
    return console.log("hello " + mainjs.name);
  }
};
```

**maincs.coffee**

```
console.log "maincs starting"
console.log "maincs exporting name"
module.exports =
  name: 'John'

console.log "maincs requiring configcs"
configcs = require './configcs'
console.log "maincs calling configcs.hello()"
configcs.hello()
```

**configcs.coffee**

```
console.log "configcs starting"
console.log "configcs requiring maincs"
maincs = require "./maincs"
console.log "configcs exporting hello"
module.exports =
  hello: ->
    console.log "hello #{maincs.name}"
```

So when we run them, we get different output (as you have seen). I've highlighted the interesting bit below.

```
node mainjs.js
mainjs starting
mainjs exporting name
mainjs requiring configjs
configjs starting
configjs requiring mainjs   #<--- Note the top-level mainjs.js code does not re-execute
configjs exporting hello
mainjs calling configjs.hello()
hello John
```

---

```
coffee maincs.coffee 
maincs starting
maincs exporting name
maincs requiring configcs
configcs starting
configcs requiring maincs
maincs starting      # <-- Look, the top-level maincs.coffee code is re-executing
maincs exporting name
maincs requiring configcs
maincs calling configcs.hello()
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'hello'
```

So I think this behavior has to do with how the node.js require system module cache works and the transpile-on-the-fly coffeescript interpreter. Basically, if the `maincs = require "maincs"` causes a re-executing of the top-level code in the `maincs` module, we hit a circular dependency situation where node is going to provide `maincs` an unfinished copy of the `configcs` exports object.

Please read the [node.js documentation on cyclic dependencies that explains this behavior](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#all_cycles) (at least partially).

Now, the interesting bit is that if you make sure that the `hello` function is exported **before** you require `maincs`, you can get away with this partially. However, referencing `main.name` from within the `hello` code won't work because main will be undefined when that first executes.

**maincs2.coffee**

```
console.log "maincs2 starting"
console.log "maincs2 exporting name"
module.exports =
  name: 'John'

console.log "maincs2 requiring configcs2"
configcs2 = require './configcs2'
console.log "maincs2 calling configcs2.hello()"
configcs2.hello()
```

**configcs2.coffee**

```
console.log "configcs2 starting"
console.log "configcs2 exporting hello"
module.exports =
  hello: ->
    console.log "hello from configcs"
console.log "configcs2 requiring maincs2"
maincs2 = require "./maincs2"
```

---

```
coffee maincs2.coffee
maincs2 starting
maincs2 exporting name
maincs2 requiring configcs2
configcs2 starting
configcs2 exporting hello
configcs2 requiring maincs2
maincs2 starting
maincs2 exporting name
maincs2 requiring configcs2
maincs2 calling configcs2.hello()
hello from configcs
maincs2 calling configcs2.hello()
hello from configcs
```

So basically, this behavior is the combination of both how modules are cached by `require`, how that interacts with cyclical dependencies, and some aspect of the coffee transpiler itself. Note that transpiling the .coffee to .js and executing with node avoids this problem both in regular coffeescript with the IIFE wrapper and bare coffeescript with no wrapper, so the IIFE wrapper doesn't seem to matter (node basically adds its own anyway).

Comment: awesome detail, thanks for that! any 'cure' other than re-designing the pattern or reverting to plain JS?

Comment: Usually circular dependencies are a design smell. If you have a module called "config", it probably shouldn't require the main module. I think you can explicitly code around it in coffeescript by detecting when it happens and re-requiring the module. Haven't tried that yet though.

Comment: I'm using 'express', and need to access global environmental variables - ideally, without explicitly setting them as global. It's a design pattern I've seen a lot of express-based apps use, although there's probably better ways to do it.

Comment: IMHO this is a bug in coffeescript -- if not in the transpiler, then certainly in the doc which claims 1-1 compatibility. Has it been reported?